# Mongo - rs.initiate() Error Code 76

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongoDB and am trying to use the following.

```
res = rs.initiate(
{
    "_id" : "ireland",
    "members" : [
        { _id:0,host:myName+".local:"+"27000" },
        { _id:1,host:myName+".local:"+"27001" },
        { _id:2,host:myName+".local:"+"27002" }
    ]
}
```

);

I then get the following error message.

```
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "This node was not started with the replSet option",
"code" : 76,
"codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
```

}
I have looked around online with no luck. I found some similar questions on here but none of the answers helped.

Comment: Have you tried by  IP address in host

Answer (score 1):

You need to start mongo server on all the nodes(port) using the --replSet option before initiating the replication set.
To do so, start the mongo server on each port using following command (each in a new cmd prompt):

```
 mongod --dbpath [databasepath] --port 27000 --replSet "ireland"
 mongod --dbpath [databasepath] --port 27001 --replSet "ireland"
 mongod --dbpath [databasepath] --port 27002 --replSet "ireland"
```

Once the servers are running you can initiate the replication using your command:

```
res = rs.initiate(
{
    "_id" : "ireland",
    "members" : [
        { _id:0,host:myName+".local:"+"27000" },
        { _id:1,host:myName+".local:"+"27001" },
        { _id:2,host:myName+".local:"+"27002" }
    ]
}
```

Make sure the **_id** field of the replication configuration is same as the replSet name.

Comment: what is databasepath? Is it where mongodb is installed?

Comment: It is where you want to store data.

Comment: I am new to mongodb. I have just installed it. I have not configured any other details. Can you please tell me what is the default path or is there something else?

Comment: You need to create a folder manually and put that location as dbpath

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to kill a redundant instance of MongoDB.

On Linux or Windows (using git bash) enter command to obtain process ID:

```
ps -alW | grep mongod.
```

On Linux or Mac kill the process using:

```
kill -9 3139
```

On Windows, kill the process using:

```
Taskkill /PID 3139 /F
```

Answer (score 0):

My environment was Windows and solution was to restart `MongoDB` process:

`Task Manager->Services->MongoDB [run restart]`